# smarty function assign php

Tags: php, smarty

i have a function in smarty that checks if the row called "mikaphotos" is empty. If the row is empty, it's ok and doesnt happen anything, and if it's not empty..it takes the value in $path variable.
Now my assin is:

```
$smarty->assign("mikaPhotos", getTheImages("SOMEPATH",400), true);
```

and my getTheImages function is:

```
getTheImages($path,$width){
 $dirname = $path; //the path
 $images = glob($dirname."*.png");//get the png images from directory
 foreach($images as $image) {
 echo '<img src="'.$dirname.'/'.$image.'" width="'.$width.'" /><br />';//echo all the images in SOMEPATH
 }
}
```

now in my file.tpl .. i put:{$mikaPhotos} and it's not working. I think there is some problem in my code, but i do not know how to do that. any help please?

Comment: What do you mean by `it's not working`? Can you further explain that? We are getting no where if everyone would just complain `it's not working!`. Tell us what is not working. What are you getting, what do you expect to get. Are there any errors?

Comment: hi @CharlotteDunois you are right. i mean, there is no images printed in my tpl, it's white page without errors, and i expect the function will echo all the images in the folder in my tpl or my page..it's clearer now ?

Comment: Please activate php errors in the php.ini. Set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` and `display_errors` to `On`.

Comment: i did before... no problems

Answer (score 0):

Function `assign` in smarty assigns(**!**) value returned by `getTheImages` function to `mikaPhotos` variable. So, your `getTheImages` function should **return** a string instead of echoing. For example, something like:

```
getTheImages($path,$width){
    $result = '';
    $dirname = $path; //the path
    $images = glob($dirname."*.png");//get the png images from directory
    foreach($images as $image) {
        $result .= '<img src="'.$dirname.'/'.$image.'" width="'.$width.'" /><br />';
    }

    return $result;    // return html for all your images as a string
}
```

Comment: so what can i do to make {$mikaPhotos} to echo automatically all the images in a given folder ?

Comment: I said - return all images as a sting and echo them in a template.

Comment: this is my code: `function getTheImages($path,$width){
          $result = '';
          $dirname = "uploads/reko/".$path.""; //the path
          $images = glob($dirname."*.png");//get the png images from directory
          foreach($images as $image){
           $result .= '<img src="'.$dirname.'/'.$image.'" width="'.$width.'" /><br />';
          }
          return $result;
         }`

Comment: What does function return when you call it directly?

Comment: didnt got you..what do u mean ?

Comment: `$r = getTheImages("SOMEPATH",400); var_Dump($r);`

Comment: it returns: string '' (length=0)

Comment: What does it mean? There no pictures?

Comment: aha, there is no pics

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks guys' i got the right code:

```
function getTheImages($path,$width){
                                        $result = '';
                                        /*$dirname = "../uploads/reko/".$path.""; //the path
                                        $images = glob($dirname."*.png");//get the png images from directory
                                        foreach($images as $image){
                                            $result .= '<img src="uploads/reko/'.$path.'/'.$image.'" width="'.$width.'" /><br />';
                                        }*/
                                        $handle = opendir("uploads/reko/".$path."");
        while($file = readdir($handle)){
            if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
                $result .= '<img src="uploads/reko/'.$path.'/'.$file.'" width="'.$width.'" /><br />';
            }
        }
                                        return $result;
                                    }
```